# How do i restore my repo to its original state locally without changing the master repo?

Tags: git

I finished a university project, that was done in a group, on git. That was finished by November of 2019, now I am revisting the project so that I can relearn the concepts in there and I would like to know how I can revert the now finished project to its original starter code locally without modifying the remote repo. I've tried using revert, however I get some errors and am not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: I can't remove the remote as the remote is established throught the university. Ive tried hard reseting, but every time i try to run the program again it gives me my completed group project, and not the original starter code

Comment: I there any hooks will pull from remote branch before you start program?

Comment: You can search your .git directory or your boot up script whether has hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Don't revert, there's nothing to accomplish there. You're just going to ruin your branch.

Assuming you have committed the full original project code right at the start of your project and went on from there, all you need to do is checkout the commit at that point. You could probably just look at the logs for your master branch and go to the first commit.

```
$ git rev-list --max-parents=0 master
```

Should give you the hash of the first commit. Then check out that commit with a new branch (let's call it `remaster`).

```
$ git checkout -b remaster $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 master)
```